# Run multiple angular 4 apps with a common node js server(rendering)

Tags: angular, express

**How to Setup render index files front-end(angula-4 cli) & backend(angular-4 cli) manage both angular apps.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Set this code in your **server.js** in node side, **manage routings** from angular side routing file means define path like **"admin/userdetails"** here is my **server.js**.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var path = require('path');
    var config = require('./server/config/db');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '16mb'}));

    /*
        allow cross origin requests
    */
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, OPTIONS, 
        DELETE, GET");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
        "http://localhost:3000");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-
        With, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
        next();
    });
     /*
        FOR API ROUTES 
     */
    app.use('/', require('./server/routes/api'));
    /*
    FOR INDEX FILE PATH 
    */
    app.use('/root', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));  
    app.use('/backDist',express.static(path.join(__dirname,
    '/admin/dist/')));    
    app.use('/dist',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/client/dist/')));
    /*
        FOR GET IMAGE PATH 
    */
    app.use('/image',express.static(__dirname+'/admin/src/uploads'));
    /*
      FOR GET ROOT PATH 
    */ 
    app.get('/', function (req, res, err) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/dist','index.html'))
    });
    app.get('/admin/*', function (req, res) {  
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/admin/dist','index.html'))
    });
    app.get('/admin', function (req, res) { 
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/admin/dist','index.html'))
    });
    /*
       FOR CONNECTION STATUS 
    */
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {  
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
    });

/*
    FOR SET CONNECTION PORT 
*/
app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example listening on port 3000!');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: if you will develope admin panel and also front end of the app for different apps then its will definately use for manage path for access your both app at a single time.

Answer (score 0):

Set to Access-Control-Allow-Origin in your express node.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
});
```