# How to run run two Angular 5 apps on a single Express server

Tags: angular, express

In my .*angular-cli.json* file I have two Angular 5 apps, as follows:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
          "name": "userapp",
          "root": "src-user",
          "outDir": "dist-user"
          ......
        },
        {
          "name": "adminapp",
          "root": "src-admin",
          "outDir": "dist-admin"
          ......
        }
    ]

}
```

On the server configuration I use

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist-user/index.html')));
```

Now, when I run `ng build --app userapp` and `ng build --app adminapp`, two directories will be generated, *dist-user* and  *dist-admin*.

What I need to do is to set each router of the two apps to ignore each other.
How?

And the second question, regarding Express.
How to serve files from *dist-admin* when appropriate and from *dist-user* when appropriate?

Comment: The Express server is also serving the API on another port, for both apps.

Comment: Can't you to try to open 2 instance of Express server and run apps separately , Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439619/run-multiple-angular-4-apps-with-a-common-node-js-serverrendering) ?